# Django code to open sepecific tab in render_to_response in view

Tags: html, django, templates, tabs, render-to-response

In my Django code I want to implement the following flow:

1. After submitting a Html form to view
2. Redirect to next tab in same HTML form which contain next form.

This is my code so far:

```
def addnewroute(request):
 if request.method == "POST":
       # do needed

   render_to_response('useradd.html')
```

Comment: All I could think of in this moment is the following: make a new template, call it useradd1.html (or whataver) and set the active tab to the second tab.

Answer (score 0):

## Introduction

Tabs are usually a visual (UI) element; meaning that there are [CSS styles](http://htmldog.com/articles/tabs/) defining the actual tabs as "pressed" or "depressed". How the tabs "change" is defined by the implementation method you choose. Let's look at the simplest solutions.

#### Manual render (hard code / multi template)

If you prefer to build it all manually, you can add a condition to choose the correct html template, which would already be pre-styled to the correct tab pressed, and display the required content. I would not recommend this method except to learn more of how the internals work and as proof of concept.

```
def addnewroute(request):
    # ...
    if step1:
        return render_to_response('useradd-tab1.html')

    if step2:
        return render_to_response('useradd-tab2.html')
```

#### Context / Template reuse

If you prefer to reuse most of your template content you can utilize the [context dictionary argument](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/http/shortcuts/#id2) to pass a `step` variable (to define in "which tab you should be now"), and a `content` variable (containing the tab content or other switch data), into your template; which will change depending on the reached step:

```
def addnewroute(request):
    # ...
    if step1:
        return render_to_response('useradd.html', {'step': 1, 'form': form1})

    if step2:
        return render_to_response('useradd.html', {'step': 2, 'form': form2})
```

Then, use the passed context variables in your template, to define [the condition](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/builtins/#if) that toggles the `selected` style on the tabs and displays the relevant [form](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/forms/#working-with-form-templates).

```
<div id="tab1" class="tab{% if step1 %} selected{% endif %}">...</div>
{{ form.as_table }}
```

This method is very similar to the first, except the same template is reused for both steps.

## Caveats with above direct render implementations

The above methods can accomplish what you asked about; however, there are a few caveats. First, the URL remains the same, which means the user cannot navigate between steps in a persistent manner. Second, the amount of "wiring code" you would have to write (front and back-end) will be a real labor. This is why I would recommend one of the following implementations for a "stepped form".

#### Form Wizard

Django (versions >= 1.4, < 1.8) shipped with an *"optional “form wizard” application that splits forms across multiple Web pages"*. The [Django Form Wizard](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/formtools/form-wizard/) uses a specialzed `WizardView` class based view to simplify multi-step form creation. **Note:** As of Django 1.8, The form wizard was moved out of `django.contrib` into [it's own package `django-formtools`](http://django-formtools.readthedocs.org/en/latest/wizard.html).

#### Javascript

A more sophisticated solution may involve Javascript activated tabs, such as [bootstrap tabs](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs). In this case you would have to either: a. render all the forms in the same template (hidden by default, toggleable by on-click events) or b. fetch the data for the forms asynchronously. The upside of this solution is a more immediate UI feel for the user, the downside is definitely more complexity.

#### More help

If you are new to Django, templates, tabs, etc, I would suggest implementing the solutions above from the first to the last, to better understand how the internals work; and then, how you can DRY and simplify your code.

Please note that similar questions has been asked a few times on SO, such as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26745478/using-django-model-forms-form-wizard-crispy-does-not-proceed-to-second-ste), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25902433/django-form-wizard-with-jquery-steps) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15397273/formwizard-how-to-proceed-from-step-1-to-step-2-when-having-own-2-templates). So if you have any more trouble you can [try searching](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=django+form+steps) for a related answer.